# Hiding just Skype behind CyberGhost?

Tags: vpn, skype

I have two Skype accounts; one personal, that I use for friends/family, and another one I use on the Internet, with strangers etc. Also, I frequently give it to people in online games, using the chat, so we can talk later. 
Sadly some people use my Skype name to look up the IP and later (D)DoS me for reasons best known to themselves (though I suspect it's just malice).

This can be remedied by using a VPN, for instance CyberGhost. However, I find it inconvenient to shield my entire PC with it when I only need to hide SKype. Is there a way for me to just run Skype behind the VPN, without slowing down my Internet connection for other stuff?

Comment: You cannot determine a user IP address by just talking to them on skype you never directly connect to other users

Comment: @Ramhound And that's where I disagree with you: https://mostwantedhf.info/